# Reposition draggable element to initial position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have 2 issues which are as follows:

1. I have prepared js fiddle for my issue:

   I'm having left and top position assigned to each draggable item. Now, when draggable item is dropped outside of droppable area then draggable item doesn't position itself to initial position.

As per my reading, I have also tried to set top and left to 0 but it didn't work.

2. After dropping element in droppable area, what changes are required so that draggable item covers entire droppable area?

Can anyone help me with this issues?

I have included exact html and css of my dom structure.

```
Please help me if possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/6snh38sw/1/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6snh38sw/8/ - This is the best answer I got from another forum. But it still has a scope to use drag end event to stop the code from breaking as timeout is used. Can anyone help me??

Comment: Your fiddle is using a relative image path and doesn't have any javascript in it?

Comment: I think I forgot to save the fiddle. I updated everything and prepared final version. Sorry about that. 

Updated fiddle: 

https://jsfiddle.net/6snh38sw/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6snh38sw/8/ - This is the best answer I got from another forum. But it still has a scope to use drag end event to stop the code from breaking as timeout is used. Can anyone help me??